# Where is the WriteUserDictionary permission set under xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Under xamarin how do I set the permission to write to the user dictionary? It is not in one of the permissions under Android Application options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11454/writeuserdictionary-permission

In Xamarin Studio you right-click on the project and choose options.  Then under Build-->General you need to set Target Framework to be Android 4.1 or above.  You should then see a checkbox for WriteUserDictionary at the bottom of the Required Permissions list.

Comment: That was actually my post on their forum.  The check box did not come in after changing the api level. You have to select OK and then go back in and it will appear.